# How to integrate Admin Lte theme in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, admin, integrate, lte

Need Help to integrate Admin Lte theme in la ravel 5.4 , i try to integrate it but it show black pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download laravel project folder by using:

```
 composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelLTE
```

Create database named :laravel and make database related  changes in .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql    
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  
DB_PORT=3306  
DB_DATABASE=laravel  
DB_USERNAME=root  
DB_PASSWORD=null
```

Goto the folder path

```
 /var/www/html$ cd  laravelLTE
```

To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command:

```
     /var/www/html/laravelLTE$ php artisan migrate
```

In case of string error make changes in following page :

> /var/www/html/laravel/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; 

    public function boot()   
    { 
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 
    }
```

Inorder to install Admin Lte theme hit following commands in your terminal:

```
composer require "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel:4.*"    
composer update
```

To register the Service Provider edit the file

> config/app.php

And add following line to providers array:

```
  Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider::class,
```

To Register Alias edit the file

> config/app.php

And add following line to alias array:

```
'AdminLTE' => Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Facades\AdminLTE::class,
```

Get configuration file in your application from vendor package file.

```
 /var/www/html/laravelLTE$ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=adminlte –force
 /var/www/html/laravelLTE$ php artisan serve
```

thank you
  I hope this will help you to integrate adminLTE theme

Comment: How to get Get configuration file in your application from vendor package file. ? by below command ? when i execute php artisan vendor:publish --tag=adminlte –force command it gives me error "Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".