# Unable to run npm command after installing laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, adminlte

I have installed new larvel project with the name **startNew**, for the purpose of installing admin-lte I run the command

```
npm install
```

This cause a lot of error[image: This error], if anyone know another route to install admin-lte in laravel 5.7 please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed AdminLTE in Laravel 5.6 by declaring it as a dependency in package.json

```
"admin-lte": "^2.4.8",
```

You can also use composer command, if its not working for you by following command :

```
composer require "almasaeed2010/adminlte=~2.4"
```

Reference : https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/installation

For you though, the problem is just with the connection. Try using different network or try to install using Ubuntu subsystems.

//Update
After running composer try this command 
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=adminlte

It will publish the adminlte scripts to your path so you can use something like 
For CSS:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/admin-lte/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/admin-lte/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
```

For JS:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/admin-lte/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}" ></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="{{ asset('/admin-lte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script  src="{{ asset('/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Reference : 
[How to integrate Admin Lte theme in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494986/how-to-integrate-admin-lte-theme-in-laravel-5-4)

Update: 
Alternate Package:
packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte

Comment: I'll check it out and will let you know thanks brother

Comment: Yeah, let me know if it works for you. I think it should work you.

Comment: Brother second method did my work, but unable still to run adminlte when I copy the the starter.html to the welcome, my layout gets disorder, and I am following from this resource.

Comment: I think files are not loading that is why your layout is getting disordered. Goto the networks tab on chrome and refresh the webpage. It will show you which files are not loading. And then goto the project and check where your files have been saved after running composer. I created using the first command and then linked it using this code  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">

Comment: Thank you very much brother I'll try these out all and will let you know, thanks if problem persist then we can resolve it through team viewer, thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184692/discussion-between-wiki-and-dhaval-chheda).

Comment: Oh that's great. So what was the issue you were facing?

Comment: There was styling issue on my end, I have left that admin pannel

Comment: Oh anyways if you ever get that kind of issue again, the easiest way to know is the error response code when you are on the network tab.

Comment: thanks I'll keep in mind next time, where could I access you in case If I got stuck in my laravel project?

Comment: You can join this group https://gitter.im/laravel/laravel or you can pm there directly.